# Move instance to world origin using geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to move an instance to the world origin using a geometry node, but it doesn't work,
Conversely, when I try to move the sphere to the instance origin it works. Why is this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always a question of the reference point, and this is in your case always the origin of the object, which contains the *Geometry Nodes* modifier.

Since version 3.4 there is the node [Self Object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/self_object.html), which in combination with [Object Info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/scene/object_info.html) (set to *Original*) outputs the position of this object in world coordinates.

[image]

With this information you can move the geometry relative to it:

[image]